# How to I get the length or size or number of fields in a form in a django template?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I would like to write a loop like this, so that I can spread the form fields out in a table. :

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load mathfilters %}
{% load get_range %}

{% for k in form|length|div:5|floatformat|add:1|get_range %}
    <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
        {% if forloop.counter >= k|mul:5 and forloop.counter <= k|mul:5|add:4 %}
            <th>{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field.errors }}</th>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
        {% if forloop.counter >= k|mul:5 and forloop.counter <= k|mul:5|add:4 %}
            <td>{{ field|add_class:"span4" }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work, but because the code above fails on `form|length`. In order for this to work, I need to get, in a template, the number of fields in a form. Does anyone know how to do this? I've searched all over but can't find anything. The following do NOT work:

```
form.len
form.length
form|length
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `{% cycle %}`?

Comment: Hello Ignacio, many thanks for your quick reply. I looked at the django manual for more information on `{% cycle %}`, and I don't see how it would help. I still need to know how many fields are in the form so that I can add the correct number of rows to the table. Can you show an example of how I would use `{% cycle %}` above? If `{% cycle %}` could store the number of times a loop executes, then I could use two loops - one to determine the number of fields in a form, and then one to print out the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your suggestions - they helped! Here is what finally worked for me:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:5 %}
        <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if forloop.counter0 >= forloop.parentloop.counter0 and forloop.counter0 <= forloop.parentloop.counter0|add:4 %}
                <th>{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field.errors }} </th>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if forloop.counter0 >= forloop.parentloop.counter0 and forloop.counter0 <= forloop.parentloop.counter0|add:4 %}
                <td>{{ field }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you are looking for, but it sounds like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:5 %}
            <th class="span4">{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field.errors }}</th>
        {% else %}
            <th>{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field.errors }}</th>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor%}
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:5 %}
            <td>{{ field|add_class:"span4" }}</td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid - I used elements from your solution in the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I dont like this code, but it was my first idea.

```
{% for field in form %}

    {% if forloop.last %}
        {{ forloop.counter }}
    {% endif %}

{% enfor %}
```

Comment: Lalo, thanks for this. Technically this answers the question of "how do I get the number of fields in a form," but it seems that this does not preserve the value outside of the loop. Using my original approach, I would need to save that value somehow to use it in a subsequent loop, which I don't think is possible with Django templates (by design).

Answer (score 0):

form.fields I believe.

```
{% for field_name in form.fields %}
```